# Address Space of a process

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

I have two questions:-

1. Lets say that the virtual address space of a process is 32 bits i.e. 4GB. What happens if I write a **'really long'** program(to increase the code segment) so that it exceeds the prescribed limit for the code segment? Will the **behavior** be something similar to bad allocation or segmentation fault which happens when data segment increases beyond limit? Will the program at least **start before crashing**?
2. In C program layout(32 bit address space) in linux, there is a 1GB space for kernel. This space will be there in each process. But the kernel exists in the RAM at all times at one place which doesn't depend upon the process. So, does the **page table of each process** map the kernel region of virtual address space to the **same** physical memory pages? Also doesn't the kernel region in process space being 1GB, limit the total kernel size to maximum 1GB (i.e. **can't kernel size be greater than 1GB**)?

Comment: Duplicating your own question, heh? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499022/virtual-memory-concepts

Answer (score 1):

Note - your question is relevant for 32bit Linux. In 64bit, it's generally the same, but with much larger numbers, which are practically infinite (so you're only limited by the actual memory installed).

1. Your program won't start running.
   It will either fail to compile (if a single object is too large) or link (if the size of all objects together is too large). Either way, it will never start to run.
   This will probably happen on a limit significantly below 4GB, depending on the compiler.
2. The kernel is indeed limited to 1GB.
   The portion of virtual addresses above 3GB is identical for all processes. Since the tables are hierarchical, there's no real duplication - the top level table of all processes just points to the shared kernel table.
   So as you say, the kernel and everything in it (loadable modules, dynamic allocations by the kernel) is limited to 1GB. If you write kernel code, keep it simple and light.

Answer (score 1):

> Will the behaviour be something similar to bad allocation or
>   segmentation fault which happens when data segment increases beyond
>   limit? Will the program at least start before crashing?

The **loader** is a program,which loads the code and data of the executable object file into memory and then runs the program by jumping to the first instruction. As in the above scenario, loader would be unable to load hence it would not be able to start the execution of the program. There would be undefined behaviour.

> So, does the page table of each process map the kernel region of
>   virtual address space to the same physical memory pages?

No,kernel maintains some swap memory which its utilizes to store the information of the process which is not currently running. Its when kernel schedules a particular process then it maps to its physical memory.

Comment: Mapping physical memory isn't done during scheduling. It's done when paging. On scheduling, all the kernel does is set a control register to point to the process's mapping table.